# Can I somehow use optional binding for multiple variables in one line in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Can I somehow use optional binding for multiple variables in one line in Swift? I need to do something like this:

```
if let foo = fooOptional && let bar = barOptional {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update for Swift 1.2:**

From Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 Beta), you can unwrap multiple optionals with `if let`:

```
if let foo = fooOptional, bar = barOptional {
    println("\(foo), \(bar)")
}
```

---

**Before Swift 1.2**

You cannot with `if`, but you can with `switch` using ["Value-Binding Pattern"](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-XID_1004):

```
switch (fooOptional, barOptional) {
case let (.Some(foo), .Some(bar)):
    println("\(foo), \(bar)")
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine! :)

Comment: You can with Swift 1.2, which was just released! http://www.codingexplorer.com/multiple-optional-bindings-swift-1-2/ (I know this question is old, but just in case anyone comes looking, you may want to update your answer)

Answer (score 6):

It's a little clunky, but you can do this with a `switch` on a tuple of your variables:

```
var fooOptional: String? = "foo"
var barOptional: String? = "bar"

switch (fooOptional, barOptional) {
case let (.Some(foo), .Some(bar)):
    println(foo + bar)
default:
    break
}
```

The time I use this is drilling down into a nested dictionary, like a big JSON object -- it's great because you can handle each error case separately:

```
switch (dict["foo"], dict["foo"]?["bar"], dict["foo"]?["bar"]?["baz"]) {
case let (.Some(foo), .Some(bar), .Some(baz)):
    // do things
case (.None, _, _):
    // no foo
case (_, .None, _):
    // no bar
default:
    // no baz
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Before Swift 1.2**

I like using the `switch` statement for this, especially if you want to handle the four different cases.

However, if you're merely interested in the case where both optionals are `Some`, you can also do this:

```swift
if let (firstName, lastName) = unwrap(optionalFirstName, optionalLastName) {
  println("Hello \(firstName) \(lastName)!")
}
```

Where this is the definition of the `unwrap` function:

```swift
func unwrap<T1, T2>(optional1: T1?, optional2: T2?) -> (T1, T2)? {
  switch (optional1, optional2) {
  case let (.Some(value1), .Some(value2)):
    return (value1, value2)
  default:
    return nil
  }
}
```

More overloads: https://gist.github.com/tomlokhorst/f9a826bf24d16cb5f6a3

Comment: I like this option when you just want to implement the "if all are available" case, a switch with a default in code feels like overkill and this keeps your code clean.